# div toggle with another divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do here: Content 1 is in an active state when the page is open, and when "Open Map" is clicked, then Content 2 toggles with Content 1. It's the same for "Open Detail" too, and also when I close map or detail then Content 1 need to display again...

Additionally, for example after opening detail, and then opening map they need to toggle with each other. No need to display at the same time. And Content 1 needs to display again when 2 or 3 are closed...

```js
$('#show-detail').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.content3').slideToggle('slow', function(event){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
      $('#show-detail').html('Close Detail');
    } else {
      $('#show-detail').html('Open Detail');
    }
  });
});

$('#show-map').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.content2').slideToggle('slow', function(event){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
      $('#show-map').html('Close map');
    } else {
      $('#show-map').html('Open map');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="content-wrapper">
      <ul class="ul-wrap">
        <li class="li-head"><i style="color:white;" class="far fa-building"></i>Summary</li>
        <a id="show-detail" href="#"><li class="li-head-right">Open Detail</li></a>
        <a id="show-map" href="#"><li class="li-head-right">Open Map</li></a>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabs-stage">
        <div class="content1 d-flex">
          <div class="d-image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x120/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="align-top">
             Lorem Ipsum Text Text Text   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content2" style="display:none;">
          Map here
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content3" style="display: none;">
          Details Here
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#show-detail').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleViews('content3');
});

$('#show-map').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleViews('content2');
});

function toggleViews(elmClass) {
  var elm = $("." + elmClass);
  var isVisible = elm.is(':visible');

  $(".tabs-stage > div:visible").slideUp('slow', function() {
   if(isVisible) {
      $(".content1").slideDown();
    } else {
      elm.slideDown();
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <ul class="ul-wrap">
    <li class="li-head"><i style="color:white;" class="far fa-building"></i>Summary</li>
    <a id="show-detail" href="#"><li class="li-head-right">Open Detail</li></a>
    <a id="show-map" href="#"><li class="li-head-right">Open Map</li></a>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-stage">
    <div class="content1 d-flex">
      <div class="d-image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x120/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="align-top">
         Lorem Ipsum Text Text Text   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2" style="display:none;">
      Map here
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content3" style="display: none;">
      Details Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```